# Scrapy, How can I handle missign data between tags using CSS selector?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, css-selectors

I'm using scrapy to scrape data from list of site,I am using **css** selector for this.

The data is like this :

```
Name : John Doe
Address : Earth
Age : 30
```

and the html structure is:

```
<li class='title>
   <span class='q'>Name</span>
   <span class='ans>John Doe</span>
   <br>
   <span class='q'>Address</span>
   <span class='ans>Earth</span>
   <br>
   <span class='q'>Age</span>
   <span class='ans>30</span>
   <br>
</li>
```

The problem is some, some of the address are empty. There is nothing between `<span class='ans'></span>`. How do i handle this ? The scrapped data should also be empty for address with proper structure.

Here is my code :

```
'   class NmcSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'nmc'
allowed_domains = ['nmc.org.np']
start_urls = ['http://nmc.org.np/registered-practitioner.html']

def parse(self, response):
    self.log('hello' +response.url)
    for title in response.css('li.title'):
        try:
            item = {
                'name': title.css('span.Ans::text').extract()[0],
                'address': title.css('span.Ans::text').extract()[1],
                'gender': title.css('span.Ans::text').extract()[2],
                'degree': title.css('span.Ans::text').extract()[3],
                'nmc_no':title.css('span.Ans::text').extract()[4]
            }
        except:
            print("No data")
        yield item    '
```

Comment: You mean Scrapy treats empty spans differently than spans with content? In what way?

Comment: yes, it takes the data from the nearest span and put it there. if  address is missing then the output comes like name and in the address filed , age is taken and no age field. I want name , if address is empty is should show empty or Null and age

Comment: Do you expect us to create you a scraper anew? If not then it is better you should update your post with your faulty script @the new guy.

Comment: If you could just show me how to handle that missing data between the tag ?

Comment: I can hardly belive that Scrapy will return you text from another node in case required node is empty... I'm sure that your locators are just not good enough. Anyway, you should provide with code and HTML for mentioned nodes with no content... For now I vote to close the question as "too broad"

Comment: I have updated my question, please have a look

Comment: Try to use XPath instead of CSS selectors: `'name': title.xpath('//span[.="Name"]/following-sibling::span[1]/text()').extract()`, `'address': title.xpath('//span[.="Address"]/following-sibling::span[1]/text()').extract()` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use `try/except` if you will use XPath expressions:

```
for title in response.css('li.title'):
    item = {
        'name': title.xpath('.//span[.="Name"]/following-sibling::span[1]/text()').extract_first(),
        'address': title.xpath('.//span[.="Address"]/following-sibling::span[1]/text()').extract_first(),
    }
```

**UPDATE**
Here is full code (tested):

```
def parse(self, response):
    self.log('hello' +response.url)
    for section in response.xpath('//ul[@id="ImgcategoryCardiologist"]/li'):
            item = {
                'name': section.xpath('.//span[.="Name"]/following-sibling::span[1]/text()').extract_first(),
                'address': section.xpath('.//span[.="Address"]/following-sibling::span[1]/text()').extract_first(),
            }
            yield item
```

Comment: it scrapped the first data only even after removing  the _first()

Comment: I am beginner , if you could explain me what is span[1] doing , and how to extract every data. I tried the code and it jst extracted the single list.

Comment: @the-new-guy I don't know what you're talking about. See my updated code and it works for me

Comment: Thank you for your the help